# Live data Updating in Angular 8

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, angular8

Hey guys i am tyring to get data from server as soon as there add's a new in the database

1. i want to avoid making many get request with the timeout

is there a way to do that?

thanks

Comment: you can use socket.io

Comment: @Edward - it's very difficult to answer questions like this. Maybe you could provide a little bit of context as to what you have tried - what your research has yielded. You can lookup https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help on how to ask questions that get answered.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways this can be done is by using changeStreams.
More info: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/